# (Rigor/Validity of Proof) Every sequence of reals in a compact set has a convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

**[ADDED/MODIFIED]**: I began my proof with a compact set, but this was a wrong start. Although the comments are valid, I should've started with a bounded set. Because what I want to establish first is that every bounded sequence of reals has a convergent subsequence. I said this in the outline of proof but don't know why I kicked off with a compact set. Then, WLOG $[0,1]$ or $(0,1)$ would be valid. Please see below bold fonts.

I am studying undergraduate analysis. I would appreciate if you could share your 2 cent on the validity/rigor/efficiency of the below proof I provide. Thank you in advance for constructive feedback.

**Show every sequence of reals in a compact set has a convergent subsequence with a limit in the compact set.**

*Taken for granted:*

**Thm A (Nested Interval Theorem**): A nested sequence of nonempty compact set has a nonempty intersection. If the length of the interval goes to zero as n goes to infinity, $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} I_{i}$ contains a point.

**Thm B (Limit Pt & Convergent Subseuqnce)**: $x^*$ is a limit point of a sequence of reals $x^m$ IFF there is a subseuqnce $x^{m(k)}$ converging to $x^*$.

***Outline of Proof***: **First show every bounded sequence of reals has a convergent subsequence**. Then, replace closed and bounded for the definition of compact set. Use the definition of closed set having all of its limit points to finally show the sequence has a subsequence converging to a point in the compact set.

**Proof**

(1) **Suppose $x^m$ is a sequence of reals in a bounded set, WLOG, say in $[0,1]$.**

***(You can use an open set $(0,1)$ WLOG since Thm A ultimately enables us to just get that single point in the nest interval using the fact a countable number of intersections of open sets is a point on real line)***

(2) Divide $[0,1]$ into two equidistant compact intervals $[0,.5]$ and $[.5,1]$, denoted by $I_1$ and $I_1^*$.

(3) $I_1$ or $I_1^*$ contains an infinite number of terms of the sequence $x^m$. [Suppose it didn't. Then, each interval contains a finite number of terms of $x^m$. The union of finite sets is finite. But $x^m$ is an endless string of reals. This is contradiction.]

(4) WLOG, let $I_1$ be the subinterval containing an infinite number of terms of $x^m$.

(5) Repeat (2)-(4), then you get $\dots\subset I_3\subset I_2\subset I_1\subset [0,1]$ (*).

(6) By **Thm A**, our nested sequence (*) of nonempty compact set contains a single point, denoted by $x^*$.

(7) **Now, want to show $x^*$ is a limit point of the sequence $x^m$**, because by **Thm B**, this is equivalent to the existence of a subsequence converging to $x^*$.

(8) Then, need to show that $\forall\epsilon>0$ there exists an infinite number of terms $x^j$ of the sequence $x^m$ satisfying $\mid x^*-x_j\mid$$<\epsilon$.

(9) By (3), any arbitrary $j\in\mathbb{N}$, $I_j$ has infinitely many terms of $x^m$. Cherrypick a term from each $I_k$ $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$. Since the length of $I_k$ for any arbitrary $k\in\mathbb{N}$ is $(\frac{1}{2})^k$, for any large $K$,$\exists j\geq K$ from the sequence $x^m$ satisfying $\mid x^*-x_j\mid$$<\epsilon\leq (\frac{1}{2})^K$.

(10) Thus, $x^*$ is a limit point of the sequence $x^m$. By **Thm B**, there exists a subsequence $x^{m(k)}$ with limit $x^*$. **Therefore, every bounded sequence of reals has a convergent subsequence.**

(11) By definition, compact set is both closed and bounded. By (10) and because compact set is bounded, there exists a convergent subsequence.

*Does this subsequence converge to a point in the compact set?*

(12) Yes. Since it is also closed, it contains all of its limit points. Hence, by **Thm B**, the convergent subsequence converges to a point in the compact set, $[0,1]$. QED

Comment: Note that for the constant sequence $a_n=.5$, $I_1$ and $I_1^*$ both contain an infinite number of terms of $x^m$.

Comment: You can't assume WLOG that the compact set is an interval or even a finite union of such intervals. For instance, the compact set might be $\{0\} \cup \left\{\frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$.

Comment: @user340297 Theorem B does not claim that the sequence in your example should converge. It claims that $0$ is a limit point of the sequence (which is different from $0$ being the limit of the sequence), and that is true.

Comment: Are you forced to use Thm A/B to prove this result? I think there's an easier method otherwise

Comment: @kccu : I agree with you. But, the example you provided seems a collection of discrete points as to what I meant by "WLOG" was a closed and bounded interval on real line. I would still argue that [0,1] is an acceptable WLOG version of a compact set on real line.

Comment: @user340297 : Not really, but it is unclear what you mean by "easier". Do you mean fewer lines?

Comment: @FrankSwanton I find it easier, you may not. There is a direct proof yielding any bounded real sequences has a convergent subsequence using "peak"s and monotone convergence theorem

Comment: @FrankSwanton My example is a closed and bounded (i.e., compact) subset of the real line. Your proof should work if my example is the particular compact set in question, but it does not.

Comment: kccu, user340297 : ok. let me think over this please. thank you.

Comment: kccu, user340297: Thanks for the feedback. I kicked off incorrectly by trying to show every sequence of reals in a compact set has a convergent subsequence, which is true, but not the argument I work for. I should've first established every bounded sequence of reals has a convergent subsequence, then use the definition of compact being bounded, so there exists such convergent subsequence, then use the fact compact means also closed, so that subsequence converges to a point in that compact set. I said this in the outline of proof but began with incorrect and inappropriate premise lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could use some small improvements.:

Small error in (4): "WLOG let $I_1$ be THE interval which contains infinitely many terms...." Well, both $I_1$ and $I_1^*$ might.

And if I wasn't familiar with the proof I would wonder what "equidistant intervals" means.

You could say: Let $a_0=0$ and $ b_0=1$ and $I_0=[a_0,b_0].$ For non-negative integer $n,$ let $I_{n+1}=[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}] $ where $$I_{n+1}=[a_n,(a_n+b_n)/2]$$ $\quad  \quad \text  {if }$  $ \{j: a^{(j)}\in [a_n, (a_n+b_n)/2\}$ is infinite;  Otherwise let $$I_{n+1}=[(a_n+b_n)/2,b_n].$$

In (9) instead of "cherry-picking", I recommend a constructive method: Let $f(0)=1$  and let $f(n+1)$ be the least $j>f(n)$ such that $x^{(j)}\in I_{n+1}.$ Then  $f$ is strictly  increasing and $(x^{f(j)})_{j\geq 0}$ is convergent, because it satisfies the Cauchy Criterion.(... Because  for each $n$ we have $I_n\supset I_{n+1}$, so $\{x^{(f(j))}:j\geq n\}\subset I_n, $ so $\sup \{|x^{(f(j))}-x^{(f(k))}|:n\leq j<k\}\leq b_n-a_n=2^{-n}.$... No need for Theorem A.)

It would be better to use subscripts,as $x_n$ than superscripts, for terms of a series. This is standard notation and avoids confusing  indices with exponents.

It is true that a subset of $\mathbb R$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded, but this is not the general def'n of compactness.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Let me read this through.

Answer (score 1):

As @kccu mentioned in the comment in general compact set does not have to be an interval and you cannot assume (1). Intervals are **totally** different from discrete sets in many ways.

But small modification can be used to achieve the same effect: since the sequence is bounded there exists $n$ such that $[-n,n]$ contains all of $x_m$. Then it follows there exists some $[k,k+1]$ that contains infinitely many $x_m$'s.

But notie that it is possible $x_m$ are all equal so in fact it contains finitely many points from the set $\{x_m:m\ge 1\}$. But You can say, there are infinitely many $m$ such that $x_m \in [k,k+1]$.

Comment: ok. let me think over this please. thank you.

Comment: kccu, user340297: Thanks for the feedback. I kicked off incorrectly by trying to show every sequence of reals in a compact set has a convergent subsequence, which is true, but not the argument I work for. I should've first established every bounded sequence of reals has a convergent subsequence, then use the definition of compact being bounded, so there exists such convergent subsequence, then use the fact compact means also closed, so that subsequence converges to a point in that compact set. I said this in the outline of proof but began with incorrect and inappropriate premise lol